# How to add keycloak sms authenticator jar file to Keycloak?

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I have a Keycloak server and Spring application with Docker. I want use [keycloak-sms-authenticator](https://github.com/gwallet/keycloak-sms-authenticator) library so I read the documents but did not understand that where is the
*KEYCLOAK_HOME* and I can not add jar files to Keycloak, for configure the sms authenticator.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Got any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

KEYCLOAK_HOME home is your keycloak installation directory.
You can add a providers folder there and copy the jar of  keycloak-sms-authenticator

Comment: Where actually we can find the JAR file? it is not in the GIT.

Comment: inside project readme file -> `$ cp target/keycloak-sms-authenticator.jar _KEYCLOAK_HOME_/providers/`
looks like you should run maven build  and then copy jar from target folder it into your _KEYCLOAK_HOME_ directory

Comment: I found the answer we need maven for creating the JAR file. We can user `maven install` or `maven package` commands to generate a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

**Where is KEYCLOAK_HOME**

If you are using Docker, KEYCLOAK_HOME usually is the `/opt/keycloak/lib` folder.

[image]

**How to generate JAR file**

To upload a JAR file, you need to generate the JAR file using the code. To create JAR file, you need MAVEN installed in your system. Once you installed maven you can use either of the following command,

```
maven package
```

or

```
mvn -e clean install
```